# Cannot add postgres container into pgadmin4 container

Tags: postgresql, docker, pgadmin-4, docker-network

I'm fairly new to docker and I want to set up a PostgreSQL database and manage it with pgadmin4. Both in docker.
Unfortunately, I cannot add the PostgreSQL database to pgadmin4
I created both containers via portainer and chose the latest docker hub images.
When creating both containers, I chose "bridge" as the network type.
[Both containers in portainer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tbg02.png)

As you might see in this picture, they share the same network and are not isolated from each other.
Are there any additional steps to do?

Comment: Do you get any output you get when trying to connect? Have you tried connecting from a local pgadmin first? Usually the log output will give you a clue on what could be going wrong.

Comment: pgadmin4 gives me the following output:
Unable to connect to server:

could not connect to server: Host is unreachable
Is the server running on host "172.17.0.3" and accepting
TCP/IP connections on port 5432?.

Comment: Was this the message when trying from pgadmin4 inside docker or on your host? If from docker, try running on the host first. I think the network seems fine. What connection parameters do you use for reaching the server?

Comment: This is the message when trying from pgadmin4 inside docker. In pgadmin, I just entered the IP of the Postgres docker container with the default port and my credentials.